# Image disappearing after adding \(var) in Image

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I am a beginner to Swift, SwiftUI, and using Xcode. I have been doing a couple of online tutorials and came across a problem when doing this bonus challenge.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var userCredits = 1000
    @State var slot1 = 1
    @State var slot2 = 1
    @State var slot3 = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("SwiftUI Slot!")
                .font(.system(size: 38))
                .fontWeight(.medium)
            Spacer()
            Text("Credits: \(userCredits)")
            Spacer()
            
            HStack{
                Image("apple\(slot1)")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                
                Image("cherry\(slot2)")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                
                Image("star\(slot3)")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            }
            Spacer()
            Button("Spin") {
                slot1 = Int.random(in: 1...3)
                slot2 = Int.random(in: 1...3)
                slot3 = Int.random(in: 1...3)
                
                if slot1 == slot2 && slot2 == slot3{
                    userCredits += 15
                }
                else {
                    userCredits -= 5
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

The images of the apple, cherry, and star disappear when I put the (slot#) after it

I tried taking out the (slot#) but that will simply display the picture of the images and not change them nor make the game work as intended

Comment: What are you trying to do, what is the purpose of `slot#`? Do you have different images named "apple1", "apple2", ... in your Assets catalog?

Comment: So in my asset catalog I have "apple", "cherry", and "star" and the purpose of putting the slot# is so it corresponds with the var's at the top. Basically all the var's have a value of one and when the user hits the spin button it's supposed to randomize the images and if all images are the same then the user would get 15 points. So I need the Images to be attatched to the var's and what I did in the code works but it makes the images disappear for some reason. @JoakimDanielson

Comment: Yes they disappear because the string you pass to `Image` must be the exact name of an existing image in your asset catalog.

Comment: I see, so how would I go about attaching the vars to that image? Where they can change but still be attached to the values of the vars? @JoakimDanielson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this by declaring an array of image names:

```
let imageNames = ["apple", "cherry", "star"]
```

then use something like:

```
HStack{
    Image(imageNames[slot1])
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
    
    Image(imageNames[slot2])
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
    
    Image(imageNames[slot3])
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
}
```

Also, don't forget that Swift arrays are zero based, so your spin function should be:

```
slot1 = Int.random(in: 0..<3)
slot2 = Int.random(in: 0..<3)
slot3 = Int.random(in: 0..<3)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved my issue, is it possible you could explain to me a little about the swift arrays being zero based? Or point me in the right direction to some documentation that explains it?

Comment: Isn't this just a duplicate of my answer?

Comment: @H4R3L maybe this will help https://medium.com/swlh/zero-indexed-arrays-f752a47abf65

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to add your images into an array and then use the values for your `slot#` properties as indices for getting an image from the array

So add an array property first to your view

```
let images = ["apple", "cherry", "star"]
```

Then change the call to `Image(...)` to use this array

```
Image(images[slot1 - 1])
```

and so on for the other two